# Finding a specific keyword in a paragraph

Tags: c#, console-application

I have tried this but it does not match the string in array.
*Note. I don't want to use regex.*

```
string pgraph = ("i love zaiby and zaiby is my best friend");
string word = ("zaiby");
string[] singleword = pgraph.Split();
bool findword = singleword.Equals(word);

if (findword == true)
{
    Console.Write("keyword founded");
}
else
{
    Console.Write("keyword not founded");
}
```

Comment: Need to loop over your array, try using a for each and putting your logical check in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing an array of strings to a string.
Try the following line instead of `singleword.Equals` line:

```
bool findword = singleword.Any(w => w.Equals(word));
```

Comment: @zaiby Glad to help. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)